# An exercise from vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I do not even know how to start.

Find a symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ with the following properties. Both $[1,2,2]^T$ and $[2,1,-2]^T$ are eigenvectors. It has three distinct eigenvalues. Furthermore, $A^n=A$ for some $n>1$. How many different solutions are there?

Comment: Since $A$ is symmetric, it is possible to write $U^{-1}AU = \Lambda$ for some diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ with real entries and an orthogonal matrix $U$. The diagonal entries of  $\Lambda$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, and the columns of $U$ are eigenvectors of $A$. Since $\Lambda^n = \Lambda$, this tells you what the diagonal entries of $\Lambda$ must be (though not their order). The orthogonal matrix $U$ must be chosen so that two of its columns are proportional to the desired eigenvectors.

Comment: Do not remove the question from the question.

Answer (score 2):

So, it's a known result that symmetric matrices (over $\mathbb{R}$), have an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.  We have two eigenvectors.  In 3D, a two perpendicular vectors span a plane, so the third vector perpendicular to the first two will be the vector perpendicular to this plane, and therefore unique (up to a constant factor).

It can be shown that the vector perpendicular to those two is of the form $k(-2,2,-1)$ for some constant $k$ (a simplistic way to show it is to assume the vector is of the form $w=(a,b,c)$, then assume that $w\cdot v_1=0$ and $w\cdot v_2=0$, where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the known eigenvectors).  So this vector will be an eigenvector.

It's a known result that any real symmetric matrix $A$ can be written as $A=QDQ^{-1}$ for a diagonal matrix $D$, and orthogonal matrix $Q$ (this is called *diagonalization*).  Let's consider the $n$-th power of this:

$A^n=(QDQ^{-1})^n=(QDQ^{-1})(QDQ^{-1})...(QDQ^{-1})=QD^nQ^{-1}$.

So, your question is equivalent to finding a diagonal matrix with three distinct eigenvalues (so not the identity matrix) such that $D^n=D$ for some $n$.  Exponentiating a diagonal matrix is equivalent to exponentiating each element of the matrix, so we would get:
\begin{align}
D^n&=
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1&&\\&\lambda_2&\\&&\lambda_3
\end{pmatrix}^n=
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1^n&&\\&\lambda_2^n&\\&&\lambda_3^n
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Where any absent terms are understood to be zero.  So finding $D^n=D$ is equivalent to solving $\lambda_i^n=\lambda_i$ for each $\lambda_i$.  Considering just the absolute values of this, $|\lambda_i|^n=|\lambda_i|\implies\lambda_i=\pm 1,0$.  So, your matrix will definitely have these eigenvalues.

So, we know the diagonal matrix will be \begin{align}D=\begin{pmatrix}1&&\\&0&\\&&-1\end{pmatrix}\end{align}
up to a reordering of the eigenvalues.  It's worth it to note here that the symmetric matrix we end up with will satisfy $A^n=A$ for odd $n$, as for $(-1)^n=-1$ to be true, $n$ must be odd.  So, we want to construct a symmetric matrix from this.  To do this, we just need an orthogonal matrix with its columns being our eigenvectors.  To find that, we just need to quickly normalize our eigenvectors, and then put them in.

So $(1,2,2)$ normalized is $\frac{1}{3}(1,2,2)$.  $(2,1,-2)$ normalized is $\frac{1}{3}(2,1,-2)$, and $(-2,2,-1)$ normalized is $\frac{1}{3}(-2,2,-1)$.

That gives us:
\begin{align}
Q=\frac{1}{27}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&-2\\2&1&2\\2&-2&-1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Of course, it's worth mentioning that $Q$ isn't unique - not only could we reorder the placement of the eigenvectors into the columns, but even after normalization each eigenvector has two choices of orientation ("positive" or "negative").  Regardless, we can construct a symmetric matrix now.

$A=QDQ^{-1}=QDQ^t$ (because $Q$ is orthoganal).  Note that $A^3=QD^3Q^t=QDQ^t=A$, and has the two eigenvectors you asked for (with three distinct eigenvalues).

As for how many solutions there are, you'd need to refine that question some.  If you have some matrix $A$ that fulfills those properties (like the $A$ we just constructed), then for any orthogonal matrix $Q$ $A'=Q^tAQ$ should fulfill all your properties (because $A^3=A$ will still be true due to a similar argument as why $A^3=QD^3Q^t$), and the eigenvectors/eigenvalues should remain unchanged.  On top of all of that, when constructing the first diagonal matrix and orthogonal matrices, you could reorder the eigenvalues/eigenvectors, or assign a different orientation to the eigenvectors, and get new matrices).

It may be possible that if you define an equivalence relation where $A\sim B$ when $A=QBQ^t$ for an orthoganol matrix $Q$ that computing the number of equivalence classes is actually a tractable problem.  The more I think about it, the more that each part that would give you a "different" matrix (reordering eigenvalues in $D$, having a different order of eigenvectors in the columns of $Q$, having a different orientation on eigenvectors) would really give you matrices that belong to a single equivalence class, although this would require actually showing/formalizing.  It seems like it should work out though, which is kind of cool.

Comment: Why can't we have $\lambda_3 = 0$?

Comment: Fixed argument, for whatever reason I remembered "nonzero eigenvalue" distinctly from linear algebra, but that likely has to do with proofs involving invertibility/determinants.